# Android Studio Update (3.1.2) - Entire Project Messed up

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated to Android Studio 3.1.2. After loading, I noticed that a lot of my code is in red. Unresolved symbols apparently. I have no idea how to fix this. I have been working on this for the last year and now can't do anything after the update. Please help me out.

This is just one of my classes.

[image]

I'm unsure of what my previous gradle version was, but now it is at 4.4, if that helps.

Comment: I would assume there’d be Gradle errors also. In any case seeing functional code and red marks doesn’t really give an idea what the errors are

Comment: There are no errors to give you - it states that it successfully builds. What can I show you to assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

1) Build > Clean Project
2) File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Hope will help you.

Comment: This cleaned up everything except for the fingerprint authentication. Any ideas on this? My app still won't work without it. The project compiles just fine. I use compile 'com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1' to use this functionality, but it isn't recognized at all. Still saying unrecognized symbol. My imports in the class are grayed out.

Comment: add dependency in app gradle. for example :
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1'
}

Comment: i think you need to add
  classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'